# Basic multiple conditions for loop not working

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, expression

I'm currently learning C and I'm facing a problem that I can't solve.
It's really simple, I want the numbers from 1 to 20 printed but only if they're even (meaning the output would be 2, 4, 6,...). I know how to do this but the problem is that I want to do it in a way that I put two conditions in a for loop:

```
int main() {      
    for (int i = 1;  i<=20 && i%2 == 0 ; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the second condition isn't evaluated, moreover it causes the program not to print anything. How can I do it ?

Comment: When `i` is one, what is the value of `i%2`?  `for` loops **stop** when the condition (middle of the two `;`) expression evaluates to zero.  They don't skip an iteration - they **stop**.  Or in this case, never run.

Comment: The loop condition means "loop while the *full* condition is true". If `i%2 == 0` is false, the loop will end. You need to add a check (`if`) inside the loop.

Comment: You can avoid the whole check for even number with `for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second condition is evaluated. It is because it is evaluated the loop does not iterate.

The initial value of `i` is equal to 1. So the sub-expression `i%2 == 0` evaluates to false.

You could use an if statement within the loop like

```
for (int i = 1;  i<=20; i++) {
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

If you want to place the expression `i % 2 == 0` in the condition of the loop then the loop can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    for ( int i = 1;  ( i % 2 == 0 ? i : ++i ) <= 20; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: I like your solution even if some programmers will complain that it is not recommended at all. Could you add some explanations ? For example why you use `++i` and not `i++`. I know the reason (`<=21` for example does not work with `i++`) but it could be interesting to explain this trick.

Comment: @Stef1611 I am sorry. There is used ++i that to compare the already incremented value with 20.

Comment: Sure ? With `i<=21` and `i++`, 22 will be printed. It is the problem of pre and post increment.

Comment: @Stef1611 The previous comment was wrong. I though that there is used the operator && in the condition.:) But this operator was used in the original question.

Comment: I found very clever to use ( i % 2 == 0 ? i : ++i ) instead of ( i % 2 == 0 ? i : i++ ) in your answer. But not so obvious, that is why I allowed myself to ask you to add some explantion

Answer (score 1):

Both conditions are evaluated - that's why the loop never gets going, in fact. When `for` starts, it sets `i` to 1, and immediately does the loop termination check: `1<=20 && 1%2==0`. This reduces to `true && false` and finally to `false`. So the `for` loop won't do anything else: the very first check fails.

Remember: *a failure of the condition check in the `for` loop **terminates** the loop*!

Instead, you need to write what you meant - it'll be more readable and will work, too! You said:

> I want the numbers from 1 to 20 printed *but only if they're even*

That translates directly to C (the return is unnecessary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // for all numbers from 1 to 20
    for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
        // print out only those that are even
        if ((i%2) == 0) printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

You can [try this out online!](https://onlinegdb.com/BJpN691DU).

Answer (score 0):

The loop stops as soon as the condition fails. Since `i%2 == 0` fails for `i = 1`, the loop stops immediately.

You need to put the even check inside the loop, not in the `for` condition.

```
int main() {      
    for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```